# No module named 'instance' while trying to run a Flask app

Tags: python, flask

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 6, in <module>
        from app import create_app, db
      File "C:\Users\miran\Dropbox\PyReddit-master\app\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        from instance.config import app_config
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'instance'
```

I am testing out this repository (https://github.com/tuvtran/PyReddit) and it keeps telling me there is no module instance, I have searched but found nothing that helped the error. The venv is in the same folder as the script.

Comment: You should create a directory/folder called `instance` and put a file called `config.py` in there.

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik Thank you, it helped but throwed another error at me, ```ImportError: cannot import name 'app_config' from 'instance.config'``` but it seems like the repository error because I feel like ```config.py``` should not be left empty. I will have a deeper look at the repo and try to get the config working. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I guess that it should actually be an `app_config.py` file within the `instance/config/` directory...

Comment: And the reason you don't see `instance/` or any subdirectories in the repository is that it is ignored in the .gitignore file: https://github.com/tuvtran/PyReddit/blob/master/.gitignore#L60

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik ```TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable``` is the new error. I feel like there are going to be so many more errors it might just be better to find a different repository or start from scratch.

Comment: Another repository might be better, yes. Because they should have documented how to handle the instance directory.

Comment: Okay, I will try and find a better repository although this was hard to find. Thanks for the help. Have a nice day.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: @Dharman I wanted to delete the post but can't.

Comment: It's because there is an answer. You can't delete a post that was found useful by other people.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially this is occurring because the `app\__init__.py` is is importing a file in the `instance` directory. As per [the Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#instance-folders), this directory normally contains instance configuration overrides default configurations.

Unfortunately, the project currently saves its default configurations in this directory, but it is not checked into Git (see `.gitignore`). To fix this:

1. Remove `from instance.config import app_config`
2. Add a configuration file following [these instructions](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#development-production)
3. Import the configuration file you just created
4. Replace `app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])` with `app.config.from_object(your_configuration)`